# jsPDF ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, window, jspdf, referenceerror

I need to create a PDF in Javascript. I have found the npm Package "jsPDF". I have installed "jsPDF" with `npm install jspdf`. It succesfully installed, but when I execute the fowolling code:

```
const jspdf = require ('jspdf');
let doc = new jspdf();

doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.text(35, 25, 'PDF with jsPDF!');
```

I get an error which says `ReferenceError: window is not defined`.

Do anybody know what's wrong in my code or if some imports are missing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem happen when jsPDF is used in server side. Check this pull request [Refactor acroform.js so that it is working in node.js and enable tests for IE 11](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/pull/1454)

Answer (score 1):

What ended up working for me, since I was incorporating Server Side Rendering, was creating an environment variable to see if I was in the browser then wrapping your code above with this flag.

```
if(process.env.BROWSER){
    const jspdf = require ('jspdf');
    let doc = new jspdf();

    doc.setFontSize(40);
    doc.text(35, 25, 'PDF with jsPDF!');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this:

```
npm install jspdf
```

In the node_modules/jspdf/dist/ folder you will see a jspdf.node.min.js file replace jspdf.min.js with this.

Then the following code will generate a pdf.

```
//This is a fix for the ReferenceError: window is not defined
//
global.window = {document: {createElementNS: () => {return {}} }};
global.navigator = {};
global.btoa = () => {};

var fs = require('fs');
var jsPDF = require('jspdf');

var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.text(35, 25, 'PDF with jsPDF!');

var data = doc.output();

fs.writeFileSync('./document.pdf', data);

delete global.window;
delete global.navigator;
delete global.btoa;
```

Answer (score -3):

replace this:

`const jspdf = require ('jspdf');
let doc = new jspdf();`

with this:

`import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');`